# Get the right REGEX expression for mariadb query

Tags: sql, regex, mariadb

Query:

```
SELECT
t1.package
FROM
(
SELECT 'openstack-neutron-12.1.0-2.el7ost.noarch' AS package UNION
SELECT 'openstack-neutron-12.1.1-1.el7.noarch' AS package UNION
SELECT 'openstack-neutron-common-12.1.0-2.el7ost.noarch' AS package UNION
SELECT 'openstack-neutron-common-12.1.1-1.el7.noarch' AS package
) AS t1
WHERE t1.package REGEXP "[^openstack-neutron-´digit]"
```

Need: I want the two first rows, I just wish the main neutron package so I think if I filter second hifen with next being a digit, the pattern will be ok.

This is mariabd.

Someone can help?

EDIT: `'((?i)openstack-neutron-api-(?-i))\\d.*'`.
This works directly on sql client, but I'm having problems with PHP (Really Strange)
I really didn't know that the characters changed so much in REGEX depending on languages.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you selecting `openstack-neutron-common-....` if you don't need them?

Comment: This is just a dummy example of a large database with several sub-queries that I have

Comment: Could you show your PHP code?

Comment: I created another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527380/same-query-diferent-platforms-diferent-results-with-regexp cause maybe is related to php

Comment: @davser - "Square brackets" (`[]`) are for "character class".  "Parentheses" (`()`) are used for grouping.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is one digit or more after the second -. You need to use + like this :

```
SELECT
t1.package
FROM
(
SELECT 'openstack-neutron-12.1.0-2.el7ost.noarch' AS package UNION
SELECT 'openstack-neutron-12.1.1-1.el7.noarch' AS package UNION
SELECT 'openstack-neutron-common-12.1.0-2.el7ost.noarch' AS package UNION
SELECT 'openstack-neutron-common-12.1.1-1.el7.noarch' AS package
) AS t1
WHERE t1.package REGEXP "openstack-neutron-[0-9]+"
```

Comment: @davser - Please be more specific -- Does it return 0 rows?  all 4?  Something else?

Comment: Probably should "anchor" (`^`) the regex on left.  The `"` is optional _in this context_ because the requirement was to have at least one digit.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
WHERE t1.package REGEXP '^openstack-neutron-[0-9]'
```

The `^` ensures that the string starts with the pattern.  You only need to look for one digit based on your description.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=7b805273198c6f0d61e6def5a6b94f5c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @davser . . . it works when I try it.  I added a fiddle.