# Same Query, Diferent Platforms, Diferent Results with REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query in PHP. No error and No Values.

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT main.a as pkg, COUNT(1) as count
FROM
(SELECT node, JSON_EXTRACT(packages, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(PATH, '$[0]'))) AS a FROM 
(SELECT packages, JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'all',  'openstack-nova-api-%', NULL, '$.packages[*]') AS PATH, cloud, node FROM Node WHERE JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'all',  'openstack-nova-api-%', NULL, '$.packages[*]') IS NOT NULL AND cloud = 'ch-dc-os-dhn-56') AS sub 
UNION
SELECT node, JSON_EXTRACT(packages, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(PATH, '$[1]'))) AS a FROM 
(SELECT packages, JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'all', 'openstack-nova-api-%', NULL, '$.packages[*]') AS PATH, cloud, node FROM Node WHERE JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'all', 'openstack-nova-api-%', NULL, '$.packages[*]') IS NOT NULL AND cloud = 'ch-dc-os-dhn-56') AS sub 
UNION
) AS main
WHERE main.a is not null AND main.a REGEXP '((?i)openstack-nova-api-(?-i))\\d.*'
GROUP BY main.a");


 $query->execute();

 $result = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
 echo json_encode($result);
```

If I use any mysql client. This will return my record count. All Good.

Why this is not working with PHP?? Do I have to escape the REGEX Pattern?? Does that make sense?

Comment: You've only prepared the query, you haven't executed it or fetched the results from it.

Comment: Sorry, Didn't paste all the code, because I know the problem is on the REGEXP, if I remove that everything is ok

Comment: Are your parentheses supposed to be literal characters in the regex?

Comment: the issue is probably the `$` sign that you need to escape. 
You can try to switch the single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: There is no `$` in the regex @Nathanael

Comment: What is the pattern you're trying to match? Can you give us un example?

Comment: of course there is no `$` in the regex, but you do have multiple `$` signs in the full query and the full query is wrapped in double quotes, so php will attempt to interpret the value of the variables (which don't actually exist) and removing all `$` signs from the query

Comment: But the OP [specified that the regex was the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527380/same-query-diferent-platforms-diferent-results-with-regexp?noredirect=1#comment112336454_63527380) and that there was no problem with the interpolation of the variables.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard he also says the query is working in his mysql client, so the problem is likely not the Regex

Comment: I am assuming he is replacing variables when running in his MySQL client. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The problem is in the REGEX, the $ variables are totally ok. If I remove the REGEX everything works fine. The Pattern of regex is also fine if I run the query directly, so don't worry about the data. It should show something like 3, openstack-nova-api-12.2.4.1. The Regex is just for not matching things like opentack-nova-api-blabla-12.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess one of the following would work

```
$query = $connection->prepare('SELECT main.a as pkg, COUNT(1) as count
FROM
(SELECT node, JSON_EXTRACT(packages, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(PATH, \'$[0]\'))) AS a FROM 
(SELECT packages, JSON_SEARCH(packages, \'all\',  \'openstack-nova-api-%\', NULL, \'$.packages[*]\') AS PATH, cloud, node FROM Node WHERE JSON_SEARCH(packages, \'all\',  \'openstack-nova-api-%\', NULL, \'$.packages[*]\') IS NOT NULL AND cloud = \'ch-dc-os-dhn-56\') AS sub 
UNION
SELECT node, JSON_EXTRACT(packages, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(PATH, \'$[1]\'))) AS a FROM 
(SELECT packages, JSON_SEARCH(packages, \'all\', \'openstack-nova-api-%\', NULL, \'$.packages[*]\') AS PATH, cloud, node FROM Node WHERE JSON_SEARCH(packages, \'all\', \'openstack-nova-api-%\', NULL, \'$.packages[*]\') IS NOT NULL AND cloud = \'ch-dc-os-dhn-56\') AS sub 
UNION
) AS main
WHERE main.a is not null AND main.a REGEXP \'((?i)openstack-nova-api-(?-i))\\d.*\'
GROUP BY main.a');
```

or

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT main.a as pkg, COUNT(1) as count
FROM
(SELECT node, JSON_EXTRACT(packages, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(PATH, '\$[0]'))) AS a FROM 
(SELECT packages, JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'all',  'openstack-nova-api-%', NULL, '\$.packages[*]') AS PATH, cloud, node FROM Node WHERE JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'all',  'openstack-nova-api-%', NULL, '\$.packages[*]') IS NOT NULL AND cloud = 'ch-dc-os-dhn-56') AS sub 
UNION
SELECT node, JSON_EXTRACT(packages, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(PATH, '\$[1]'))) AS a   FROM 
 (SELECT packages, JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'all', 'openstack-nova-api-%', NULL, '\$.packages[*]') AS PATH, cloud, node FROM Node WHERE JSON_SEARCH(packages, 'all', 'openstack-nova-api-%', NULL, '\$.packages[*]') IS NOT NULL AND cloud = 'ch-dc-os-dhn-56') AS sub 
UNION
) AS main
WHERE main.a is not null AND main.a REGEXP '((?i)openstack-nova-api-(?-i))\\d.*'
GROUP BY main.a");
```